# AngularJS index page without #/home

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web application. When I load my site in a browser I type www.domainname.com. The browser loads the page and immediately my browser url changes to www.domainname/home.

How can avoid this? I would like the browser shows www.domainname.com when I´m in index.html

**UPDATE:**

Please see my app.js:

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);   

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];           

    $routeProvider.when('/about', {templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl'});    
    $routeProvider.when('/contact', {templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
    // More routing
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
    // More routing
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'}); 
  }])
  .config(function(AngularyticsProvider) {
    AngularyticsProvider.setEventHandlers(['Console', 'GoogleUniversal']);
  }).run(function(Angularytics) {
    Angularytics.init();
  });
```

Comment: What does your routing look like? Give us something to work with, please. Also, consider updating AngularJS. Your version is very old.

Comment: Please, see my updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you replaced:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
```

by

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

and added:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
```

*NOTE*: and as @isherwood rightly commented below:

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
```

can be removed altogether, to avoid having both '/' and '/home' pointing to the same route.

Comment: This should do it. The last line is a change, though, and not an addition.